# Difference between EventDispatcher and Messenger

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, symfony-messenger

What is the basic difference between dispatching an Event by `Messenger` and dispatching an Event by Symfony `EventDispatcher` Component ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Symfony Messenger` is a tool to help you building a bus messenger system. 
Typically, you would use it if your application needs to communicate with **external** services (using an AMQP protocol, for example).

The `EventDispatcher` system gives your components the ability to communicate between them. 
You'll use this system if you want to make **inner parts** of your application communicate.

Answer (score 3):

As you've already tagged this question with RabbitMQ: have you tried to use the EventDispatcher and RabbitMQ? I don't think this is possible.

But to cite the official documentation, located at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html:

> The Messenger component helps applications send and receive messages to/from **other applications** or via message queues.

The pure ability to handle a message in another request (through using a transport) makes a huge difference to the EventDispatcher, which handles all given events in the same instance of your application. Restarting the application (through a new shell call, or a new web server request) will definitely kill all events that have not been handled yet through the EventDispatcher, but those stored using a transport might still be there